# CURL PHP code not delivering transnational SMS on LIVE SERVER

Tags: php, curl, server, sms, send

I wish to send transactional SMS from my live server, but unfortunately it's not working on the live server and it's working on the local server. I went through near by all questions and answers related this question over the net and I followed all the changes which people suggested over here but still the problem is not resolved.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction over here?

I Checked everything on live 1) Curl enabled 2) PHP version is OK 3) Curl executes without any error but no result

```
{

 $SMSURL='http://103.250.XX.XX/SendSMS/sendmsg.php?uname=XXXX&pass=XXXX&send=XXXX&dest=830800XXXX&msg=Hello World Message!';
  $ch = cURL_init();
 $params = array(
            'domain' => array(
            '103.250.XX.XX',
            '103.250.XX.XX'
              )
        ); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $SMSURL,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params)
          ));

            // grab URL and pass it to the browser
            cURL_exec($ch);
            $response = curl_getinfo($ch);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($response);
            print_r(curl_error($ch));
            print curl_errno($ch);
            echo "</pre>";
            // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
            cURL_close($ch);
```

}

[image: Result which I get on browser]